# Call to undefined method error when I try to use links()

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, centos

When I try to use $student->links() I see this error :

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
>   Call to undefined method App\Student::links()

I checked the controller, model etc but all of them seem OK... How can I fix this?

(I tried this code both on my Macbook and VPS -CentOS7- but same problem occurs)

That part of my view looks like this:

```html
      </tr>
            @endforeach
           </tbody>
         </table>
            {{ $student->links() }}
         </div>
       @endsection
```

Comment: if you want to use 'links()' you should 'paginate()' your '$student' variable... please post the controller

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
{{ $student->links() }}
```

to

```
{{ $students->links() }}
```

(use plural form).

Answer (score 0):

You need to paginate in your backend code. `$students = App\Student::paginate(15);`

And then you can access the `links()`

```php
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($students as $student)
        {{ $student->name }}
    @endforeach
</div>

{{ $students->links() }}
```